# pagination directive does not give me filtered data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I am using this pagination directive. : https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination

I am facing issue over getting filtered data.

we use ng-repeat to get filtered data like this : so if I use sam object it will give me filtered data.

```
ng-repeat="s in sam =(groups.listingDescriptionData | filter: search) | limitTo: 10"
```

If i try to use like this with this directive then I am not getting filtered data :

```
dir-paginate="ldd in perman  = (groups.listingDescriptionData | filter: search) | orderBy: sortingOrder |  itemsPerPage: pageSize"
```

This is very specific to the above mentioned directive issue if anybody has any idea or faced any issue please suggest me some solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to make sorting. You can look at [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/dWfVG7OFjkgmTe8Z4kDx?p=preview)

```
<li dir-paginate="meal in meals | filter:q | orderBy: order?'key':'-key' | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage">{{ meal.key + ': ' +meal.val }}</li>
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts but I am facing issue over filter. means if you add any filter text than the filtered list I am not getting from dir-paginate directive.

Comment: Can't understand you, filter returns filtered data. [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gJbMTzWQX0g5ClKcINqJ?p=preview)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for thank you. @saygon91. I need page specific data means after filtering if I come to 2nd page I want all the data on that 2nd page. any Idea?

Comment: @SamirShah are you using angular routing?

Comment: I am trying to get all the records of currentpage but not getting the way how to do it. any idea?